# The screen (MBP 14 M1) remains dim after viewing an HDR video

Tags: macbook-pro

My screen remains dimmed after viewing an HDR video. How do I restore its full brightness?

This occurs on YouTube. I've viewed some HDR videos using QuickTime, but a dimmed screen like I'm experiencing with YouTube doesn't persist.

The portion of the screen aside from the HDR video, dims. I have turned off automatic adjustment of brightness in the system settings. You might be able to experience it, if you find an HDR video on YouTube and play it.

MBP 14 M1

Comment: How are you viewing the video? Webpage, Quicktime player, VLC?

Comment: "Remains dimmed after" -- do you mean it goes dim after, or it dims to display the video, and doesn't restore the brightness? I presume you've turned off Automatic adjustment of Brightness in System Settings?

Comment: @IconDaemon YouTube. I've viewed some HDR videos using QuickTime, but a dimmed screen like I'm experiencing with YouTube doesn't persist.

Comment: @benwiggy The portion of the screen aside from the HDR video, dims. I have turned off automatic adjustment of brightness in the system settings. You might be able to experience it, if you find an HDR video on YouTube and play it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the answers you have provided in the comments since those can be deleted over time. The more detailed information you provide helps the community arrive at a solution for you.

Comment: If I view a video on YouTube in Safari, then the rest of the display is unaffected. We're talking windowed, not Full Screen, presumably?

Comment: @benwiggy, Try in Chrome if you have it installed. Yes, windowed not full screen. However, when I change tabs from the YouTube video, the entire screen is still dim. Every part of the screen but the HDR video is dimmed. I tried in Safari too and didn't notice my display dimming as it does in Chrome. I am using the following Chrome: Version 115.0.5790.170 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Sounds like a Chrome bug. (On top of the personal security issues and resource hogging.) Ask Chrome support.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1804965/the-screen-mbp-14-m1-remains-dim-after-viewing-an-hdr-video